# Does Windrunners combo of windrun+bkb make her invulnerable?

Tags: dota-2

Does Windrunner's Windrun + BKB (Black King Bar) make her invulnerable ?

If so, then what should be the order:

1. BKB and Windrun (my guess)
2. Windrun and BKB

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, she can take damage :

- Physical from an attack with [True Strike](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/dota2/True_Strike)
- Physical (from physical nukes such as Dazzle's Shadow wave, Slardar's Slithereen crush). Those are the spells that deals physical damage.
- Magical from spells that pierce [Spell Immunity](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/dota2/Spell_Immunity)

Comment: +1. Thanks for the reply. I agree for void, but **`Sniper headshot`** would be miss because of `Windrun` ?

Comment: From the wiki : Headshot can not be evaded

Comment: @BlaXpirit From the wiki: http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Doom, Doom is not blocked by magic imunity, you can doom someone that is BKBed, you can doom Nai'x while he rages, you can doom Juggeernaught while he spins etc.

Comment: do u study. Beacuse i have seen your answers. Must have done a lot of research.

Comment: @Luv Actully I've played the game for ~10 years so I know the answers, The wiki is just here as an evidence and for additional information

Comment: You cannot doom someone trough linkens though.

Comment: @WizLiz On similar note, does OMNI become invulnerable with his Guardian Angel and Repel?

Comment: @Rakesh Kind of yes, however you still can be disabled by disable that overpass magic imunity (Viper's ult, naga net, etc) and if I'm not mistaken you still take universal and HP removal damage (which are mentionned in my answer), however I don't know if composit damage get reduced by armor

Comment: Don't forget Mixed (Leshrac Edict, Beastmaster Axes, etc.) and Physical damage nukes (Dazzle heal, Slardar stun, Alchemist DoT, etc.)

Comment: @Decency yes I did mention  Composite damage

Comment: @WizLiz Oh my mistake, forgot it had been renamed from Mixed to omposite. My point about physical damage still stands, though!

Comment: For anyone reading these comments in the future: as of the 6.82 patch, composite/mixed damage is not a thing that exists in Dota 2 anymore.